# Python trim last and sort list

Tags: python, sorting

I have list MC below:

```
MC = [('GGP', '4.653B'), ('JPM', '157.7B'), ('AIG', '24.316B'), ('RX', 'N/A'), ('PFE', '136.6B'), ('GGP', '4.653B'), ('MNKD', '672.3M'), ('ECLP', 'N/A'), ('WYE', 'N/A')]


def fn(number):
    divisors = {'B': 1, 'M': 1000}
    if number[-1] in divisors:
        return ((float(number[:-1]) / divisors[number[-1]])
    return number

map(fn, MC)
```

How do I remove B, M with fn, and sort list mc high to low.

Comment: NumPy is the right choice for number crunching.

Comment: Are you sorting by number or ticker? If by number, do you want 'N/A' to fall before or after the numbers?

Comment: What does "remove B, M" mean?  Remove from what?  The last character of the value?  What have you tried?  What does "sort list mc high to low" mean?  Sort by what?  Key?  Value?  Something else?

Comment: @seth  sorry, by sort by number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def fn(tup):
        number = tup[1]
        divisors = {'B': 1, 'M': 1000}
        if number[-1] in divisors:
            return (tup[0], float(number[:-1]) / divisors[number[-1]])
        else:
            return tup
```

The problem is that that function was meant to run on a string representation of a number but you were passing it a tuple. So just pull the 1'st element of the tuple. Then return a tuple consisting of the 0'th element and the transformed 1'st element if the 1'st element is transformable or just return the tuple.

Also, I stuck an else clause in there because I find them more readable. I don't know which is more efficient.

as far as sorting goes, use `sorted` with a `key` keyword argument

either:

```
MC = sorted(map(fn, MC), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

to sort by ticker or

```
MC = sorted(map(fn, MC), key=lambda x: x[1] )
```

to sort by price. Just pass `reversed=True` to the `reversed` if you want it high to low:

```
MC = sorted(map(fn, MC), key=lambda x: x[1], reversed=True)
```

you can find other nifty sorting tips here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Comment: its not homework, Im new to python, its better to ask than struggle  with python semantics which Im learning

Comment: I Seperated to [0], and [1] ran fn on [1] then tried to add back wasnt getting the right ans.

Comment: @user428862,  how did you separate? did you try the code I've posted? It works for me.

Comment: I wrote comment on first post.

Comment: @user428862 updated. I also included a link to the sorting howto. Struggling is better than asking most of the time. It becomes less of a struggle.